Accessing Whatsapp API account from mobile/web
we've successfully set up a Whatsapp API account and can programmatically receive (soon send) messages. However, I'd like to link the same account to phone/web to easily read/send/receive messages without making use of a third party tool.
If it's impossible to do so via WA web/mobile, is there self-hosted open source UI alternative?
Was expecting to still be able to link a business manager/API account to mobile/Whatsapp web. Not possible.
